# my image wont load..... "image not found" any ideas why?

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to load an image of me on my html canvas.....
The image is in the right folder...... I just get a weird error (as shown above) im not sure what is going on if you know please let me know.
Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,800,500)


 var img = new Image();
img.src = "science.PNG";
img.onload = function() {
context.drawImage(img, 145, 145);
};
</script>

      </body>

     </html>
```

Comment: The image shouldn't be in a folder at all, you're not calling `"images/science.PNG"` or anything

Comment: What server are you running? Can you share your folder structure? Can you edit your snippet to be a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

```
context.drawImage(img, 145, 145);
```

Try changing 'context' to 'ctx'.